# How To Communicate with Trackers and Get The Peers List?

Tags: java, bittorrent

can any one tell me How To Communicate with Trackers and Get The Peers List ? with any example...

Comment: Do you have any code yet? Did you try anything with BEncode (the bittorrent data format)? Do you have experience with network connections or a http client?

Comment: i have extracted the MetaInfo[info_hash='b52ae30711444eedf0a9bd7dcc7493a0eebb9f2d', announce='http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce', name='Under.The.Tonto.Rim.1947.DVDRip.XViD-SPRiNTER [NO-RAR] - [ www.torrentday.com ]', files=[[Read This Guide Now.txt], [sprinter-xvid-tonto.avi], [sprinter-xvid-tonto.nfo], [www.Torrentday.com.txt]], #pieces='2798', piece_length='262144', length='733460723'] the thing is i need to get the peers from the tracker now ...

Answer (score 0):

From the [bittorent API project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitext/):

> Simple and easy-to-use API that should permit any developer to create new JAVA applications that require the use of Bittorrent Protocol. Provided examples show very simple torrent creator and publisher, Bittorrent client and tracker.

What you're looking for should be in the example code.

---

**Further Reading:**

- [Tracker HTTP/HTTPS Protocol](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol)

Comment: cant we view in browser as http request ..tracker http://thepiratebay.org/scrape?info_hash=b52ae30711444eedf0a9bd7dcc7493a0eebb9f2d i found in bit torrent specification but it didnt work

Comment: A http request by your browser does not send any torrent-specific information to the tracker. You have to use the API or write your own mini-client that sends BEncode data to the tracker via HTTP!